# What's the error with following code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm using PHP, jQuery, Colorbox- ajQuery lightbox plugin, etc. for my website. I'm not getting why the error is coming! Can you help me in this regard please?
 My code is as follows:

```
<span class="submit edit_user_transaction_status" value="{$control_url}{$query_path}?op=edit_user_transaction&page={$page}&txn_no={$user_transaction_details.transaction_no}&transaction_data_assign={$user_transaction_details.transaction_data_assign}&user_id={$user_id}{if $user_name!=''}&user_name={$user_name}{/if}{if $user_email_id!=''}&user_email_id={$user_email_id}{/if}{if $user_group!=''}&user_group={$user_group}&{/if}{if $user_sub_group!=''}&user_sub_group={$user_sub_group}{/if}{if $from_date!=''}&from_date={$from_date}{/if}{if $to_date!=''}&to_date={$to_date}{/if}{if $transaction_status!=''}&transaction_status={$transaction_status}{/if}{if $transaction_no!=''}&transaction_no={$transaction_no}{/if}">Update</span>

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".edit_user_transaction_status").live('click', function(e) { alert("Hallo");
      e.preventDefault();

        $.colorbox.close();

         //for confirmation that status change
         var ans=confirm("Are you sure to change status?");
         if(!ans) {
             return false;
         }  
         var post_url           = $(this).attr('value');
         var transaction_status_update = $('#transaction_status_update').val();      

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: post_url+"&transaction_status_update="+transaction_status_update,
                 data:$('#transaction_form').serialize(),
             dataType: 'json',  
             success: function(data) {              
                 var error = data.login_error;

                 $(".ui-widget-content").dialog("close");
                //This variables use for display title and success massage of transaction update              
                 var dialog_title   = data.title;              
                 var dialog_message = data.success_massage; 
                 //This get link where want to rerdirect
                 var redirect_link  = data.href;            

                 var $dialog = $("<div class='ui-state-success'></div>")
                 .html("<p class='ui-state-error-success'>"+dialog_message+"</p>")
                 .dialog({
                     autoOpen: false,
                     modal:true,
                     title: dialog_title,
                     width: 500,
                     height: 80,
                     close: function(){                                     
                         document.location.href =redirect_link;
                     }                  
                 });                    

                 $dialog.dialog('open');                    
             }          
        });
     });
});
```

I'm getting the following error in console upon Clicking on Update span:

```
TypeError: $(...).live is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

$(".edit_user_transaction_status").live('click', function(e) { alert("Hallo");
```

Can you tell me why this error is coming and what's the solution for this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is removed in 1.9+ and deprecated in 1.7+ use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead and if the element is dynamically added delegate on the closest static element like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_user_transaction_status', function (e) {
    alert("hallo")
});
```

Comment: I tried your trick but the function is not getting called now. The alert message is not getting printed.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? And what jQuery version are you using?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors at all in the console. I'm using jquery-1.9.1.min.js

Answer (score 0):

i can't comment because i have low reputation but this should work

```
$(".edit_user_transaction_status").on('click', function (e) {
    alert("hallo")
});
```